# How to eliminate all "if" statements from my validator class

Tags: java, validation, if-statement

Is there a way to eliminate all the "if" statements from this class and still maintain the exact same functionality ?

So far I managed to simplify the code by creating the 2 extra functions: isNameValid and isPhoneValid, but I need a way to get rid of **all** the "if" statements.

```
public class ClientValidator implements Validator<Client> {
    @Override
    public void validate(Client entity) throws ValidatorException {
        if(!isNameValid(entity.getName())){
            throw new ClientException("Invalid name!");
        }
        if(!isPhoneValid(entity.getPhone())){
            throw new ClientException("Invalid phone number!");
        }
    }

    private boolean isNameValid(String name) {
        return name.length() > 1 && name.length() < 100;
    }

    private boolean isPhoneValid(String phone) {
        try {
            Long.parseLong(phone);
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to have `if`s *somewhere*. Tucking them away in a function is about as good as it gets

Comment: "I need a way to get rid of all the `if` statements" - why?

Comment: I was hoping I could remove all of them. Maybe some Java 8 class ?

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar This is part of a bigger university assignment, and removing all the ifs is part of the requirements.

Comment: Ah, I was right, it smelled like homework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this :

```
@Override
public void validate(String entity) throws ClientException {
    String message = !isNameValid(entity.getName()) ? "Invalid name!"
            : !isPhoneValid(entity.getPhone()) ? "Invalid phone number!" : "";
    Stream.of(message).filter(m -> m.isEmpty()).findAny()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new ClientException (message));
}
```

Comment: what about now @SebastianGrigor

Answer (score 2):

you can try optionals and do filtering on the methods, but you miss reason specific exceptions:

```
Optional
.of(entity)
.filter(entity -> isNameValid(entity.getName())
.filter(entity -> isPhoneValid(entity.getPhone())
.orElseThrow(() -> new ClientException("Wrong client data"));
```

Comment: This looks promising.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to eliminate all the "if" statements from this class and still maintain the exact same functionality ?

Yes. It's a hack, but `if` isn't the ***only*** flow-control. Easiest I see, a `while` loop with the same logic. Like,

```
@Override
public void validate(Client entity) throws ValidatorException {
    while (!isNameValid(entity.getName())) {
        throw new ClientException("Invalid name!");         
    }
    while (!isPhoneValid(entity.getPhone())) {
        throw new ClientException("Invalid phone number!");
    }
}
```

You could also use `switch` statements like

```
@Override
public void validate(Client entity) throws ValidatorException {
    switch (isNameValid(entity.getName())) {
    case false:
        throw new ClientException("Invalid name!");                         
    }

    switch (isPhoneValid(entity.getPhone())) {
    case false:
        throw new ClientException("Invalid phone number!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of something like: using streams for filtering in order to remove the loop; that kind of thing.

Comment: @SebastianGrigor What loop? Your question has basic flow control.

Comment: While this is a perfectly fine solution, I don't think my professor will appreciate it.

Comment: @Sebastian Grigor your professor doesn't seem to appreciate good programming practice to start with

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I was giving an example on how using Java 8's stream for filtering a list will remove the otherwise necessary loop.

Comment: Ahhh.... You need to think about *composing* `Validators`; a `ClientValidator` validates a `String` and a `Long` perhaps... but that just buries the logic in the validate method; you're still left with needing some form of flow control.

Answer (score 0):

I could think of some dirty tricks like

```
public void validate(Client entity) throws ValidatorException {

    try {
        int len = entity.getName().length();
        int isshort = 1 / len;
        int islong = 1 / max (0, 100- length);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new ClientException("Invalid name!");
    }
   try {
        Long.parseLong(entity.getPhone());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new ClientException("Invalid phone number!");
    }
}
```

So no if needed